# $Expand does not work when i get one item

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I prepare Odata API for mobile application, and i have a problem with $Expand. When i use this query everything works ok.

Query:
.../odata/forms?$expand=FormFields($expand=FormFieldRadios)&$filter=FormId eq 1

But when i use this query:

.../odata/forms(1)?$expand=FormFields($expand=FormFieldRadios)

Expand does not work and items collection si empy.

My json results
[Items coolection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEqxa.png)
[One item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2StsN.png)

[My nugets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66unH.png)

ConfigureServices:

```cs
services.AddOData();
services.AddODataQueryFilter();
services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        // https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/27/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-endpoint-routing/
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Configure

```cs
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().Count().OrderBy().MaxTop(250).Expand(QueryOptionSetting.Allowed);
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices));
});
```

ModelBuilder

```cs
 builder.EntitySet<Form>("Forms").EntityType.Filter().Count().Expand(OdataDefaults.MaxExpansionDepth).OrderBy().Page().Select();
```

Form Entity

```cs
 public class Form
 {
     [Key, Required]
     public int FormId { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public int Order { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public bool Active { get; set; }

     [Required, MaxLength(255)]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public int IsDeleted { get; set; }

     [MaxLength(255)]
     public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }

     public ICollection<FormField> FormFields { get; set; } = new List<FormField>();
 }
```

Odata Controller

```cs
public class FormsController : ODataController
{
    private VillageContext _db;

    public FormsController(VillageContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    [EnableQuery(AllowedFunctions = OdataDefaults.AllowedFunctions, MaxExpansionDepth = OdataDefaults.MaxExpansionDepth, PageSize = OdataDefaults.PageSize)]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Forms);
    }


    [EnableQuery(AllowedFunctions = OdataDefaults.AllowedFunctions, MaxExpansionDepth = OdataDefaults.MaxExpansionDepth, PageSize = OdataDefaults.PageSize)]
    public IActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return Ok(_db.Forms.Find(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

EntityFramework's `Find` method does not return an `IQueryable<TEntity>` but rather `TEntity` itself. It is therefore logical that OData can no longer expand on it, since there is no expression tree anymore to "modify".
Change your function to this:

```
[EnableQuery(AllowedFunctions = OdataDefaults.AllowedFunctions, MaxExpansionDepth = OdataDefaults.MaxExpansionDepth, PageSize = OdataDefaults.PageSize)]
public IActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return Ok(SingleResult.Create(_db.Forms.Where(form => form.FormId == key)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for idea but if i use this function there is problem because function get array. I need function which get one item

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a key against your entity (forms)?

Look at the demo http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata - you'll see a key is defined so you can reference entity members by the key you choose.
  Example:

```
  <EntityType Name="Person" OpenType="true">
   <Key>
       <PropertyRef Name="UserName" />
   </Key>
```

Then as per the [OData examples](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/) you can use a query like:
GET serviceRoot/People('russellwhyte')